# How to get a reference of a const vector element from template

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I have this `main.cpp`:

```
std::string hw[] = { "Hello", "World" };
const array_appender<std::string> ha( hw, sizeof( hw ) / sizeof( hw[ 0 ] ) );

if ( /*with some other conditions*/ &( ha.at( 0 ) ) == hw )
{
  //some other stuff
}
```

And I have this template:

```
template<typename T>
class array_appender {
public:
    array_appender(T* array, size_t size) {
        append(array, size);
    }

    void append(T* array, size_t size) {
        for( int idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx)
        {
            std::cout << "value of array: " << array[idx] << std::endl;
            data.add(array[idx]);
        }
    }

    T at(size_t index) const {
        return data[index];
    }

    size_t size() {
        return data.size();
    }

    const size_t size() const {
        return data.size();
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

But I got this error for the condition of above:

```
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

And I searched for this, but solutions what I found doesn't worked for me in this case. Thank's for any ideas!

Comment: what is this `&( ha.at( 0 ) ) == hw` supposed to do? your `at` returns a value (a reference would be more natural) so what do expect to get by taking its adress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_appender<T>::at` returns `T`, which will be a temporary object (an rvalue) on the calling site `ha.at(0)`. Then you take the address of it `&ha.at(0)`, which is prohibited, hence the error "taking address of temporary".

Usually, methods like `at` return a reference to the object, so that it can be modified (if this is desired, of course):

```
T & at(size_t index) const {
    return data[index];
}
```

Then, taking the address of this lvalue is a valid operation.

Have a look at [`std::array::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at), [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), and [`std::map::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at).

Comment: @kortealma What, in the first place, made you think that `std::vector<T>` would have a member function named `add`?

Comment: @kortealma Just in case, you need `push_back` - it does what you need. And pay attention to what artoonie said: you are actually comparing pointers (memory addresses) to two separate objects, which will not be equal regardless of the objects' contents. You probably want to compare the objects themselves, not the memory addresses.

Comment: Are you sure that reference is must be there? This is working for me without, and doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `&( ha.at( 0 )`, you are taking the address (&) of a temporary variable (h.at(0)).

You can try `std::string tmp = ha.at( 0 )`, and take the address of `tmp`, but...there's no way the address of a string will be equal to an array of strings! You're comparing an address of a temporary variable to the address of a member in an object. Do you mean to compare the strings instead?

Comment: Yes, I want to get this condition return true.

Comment: consider ` if ( ( ha.at( 0 ) ) == hw[0] )`